# Click on image, click off page jquery()

Tags: jquery, html, click

I have a little test I'm doing with clicking on a image that reveals an iframe.  Then I want to click anywhere but that image (the #container div).  I can get the iframe to popup but I can't get it to hide when I click in the main div (#container).

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript"    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
$(function() {
  var moveLeft = 20;
  var moveDown = 10;

  $('a#trigger').click(function(e) {
    $('div#pop-up').show();
      //.css('top', e.pageY + moveDown)
      //.css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft)
      //.appendTo('body');
  }, function() {
    $('#container').click(function(){
    $('div#pop-up').hide();
    });

  $('a#trigger').mousemove(function(e) {
    $("div#pop-up").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
  });

   });</script>
       <style>
    h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    }
    div#container {
    width: 580px;
    margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
    }
   /* HOVER STYLES */
   div#pop-up {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   /*width: 150px;
   padding: 150px;*/
   background: #eeeeee;
   color: #000000;
   border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
   font-size: 90%;
  }
    </style>

   </head>
   <body>
<div id="container">
    <h1>Pop-out Example - pop out div on hover</h1>
    <p>
        <a href = "#" id="trigger"><img src="router.png"/></a>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="pop-up">
    <p>
        <iframe width="500px" height="350px" align= "top-left" src="http://127.0.0.1:667"></iframe>
    </p>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you are using jQuery you can do the following. The javascript instructs that if the document is clicked anywhere the `target` div is hidden. However if the click was within the boundaries of the element `target` the `hide()` is stopped by `stopPropagation()`

**Javascript**

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#target').hide();
});
$("#target").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="target">Test</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#target {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Illustrated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pyzzf/1/)

Comment: Thanks for that...I can see how that works...now if only I could get it to pop up again...I think I broke it.  Best to start fresh here I think using your model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toggle()` jQuery but i think it is deprecated.

```
$("a#trigger").click ( function() {
    $("#pop-up").toggle();
});
```